# Bamboo support in CAKE

Tags: bamboo, cakebuild

How good is Bamboo support in CAKE? We're currently on Team City but considering moving to Bamboo. What we need:

1) Report error from cake script

2) Set build number from cake script

3) Publish artifacts from cake script

All these are currently possible with Team City but I can't find anything other than **IsRunningOnBamboo** for Bamboo.

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in support in Cake for Bamboo, compared to TeamCity, isn't as good at the minute.

You should be able to report an error.  This is typically done in Continuous Integration Servers by looking for a non zero exit code.  This is what Cake does out of the box, so an error thrown from your Cake build script, should fail the build in Bamboo.

In TeamCity, setting the build number, and publishing artifacts, are done through the Service Messages that TeamCity supports.  If Bamboo has a similar feature, then there is no reason that Cake, either out of the box, or within your own script, shouldn't be able to support it.  It would just be a case of figuring out how it is done.

We would be happy to accept a PR to provide this functionality out of the box in future versions of Cake.

The current BambooProvider does provide some additional information in the form of the Build, Plan and Repository information:

https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.Bamboo.Data/BambooBuildInfo/
https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.Bamboo.Data/BambooPlanInfo/
https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.Bamboo.Data/BambooRepositoryInfo/